# Safe to call Java 8 Collection default methods on results of Collections.synchronizedX?

Tags: java, java-8

Java 8 added loads of default methods onto interfaces in the collections framework; however, the JavaDoc of the [`Collections.synchronizedX`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) methods barely changed. It is unclear to me whether calling the new default methods on the results returned by them is safe or not?

I checked Oracle JDK source and they seems to be overridden to be thread-safe, but is there any guarantee for all JDKs?

Comment: They have not changed the javadoc, which guarantees that all methods are thread safe by being synchronized. If they have not propagated that behaviour to default methods it is a bug.

Comment: @assylias However, if you see this from a perspective of a third-party pre-JDK 8 library, then again no change in JacaDoc, but all its collection wrappers are no longer thread-safe. However, I guess it also means this question cannot be realistically answered beyond the scope of the JDK.

Comment: @billc.cn: that’s why you shouldn’t use a 3rd party library for this kind of task. However, the thread safety of such a class doesn’t change due to the `default` methods. It is still as safe as before, it’s just that compound operations require additional effort, which is also just like before.

Comment: @Holger There are libraries like Guava that is just as high quality as the JDK and is well tested. Unfortunately, they do suffer from unforseen changes in the language even though the JavaDoc provides exactly the same contract as the JDK ones. [Example](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#synchronizedNavigableMap%28java.util.NavigableMap%29)

Comment: Well, such a change can’t break existing code as the existing code doesn’t know the new `default` methods. On the other hand, new code can switch to [`Collections.synchronizedNavigableMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedNavigableMap-java.util.NavigableMap-). This has nothing to do with quality but just the fact that the interface and that particular implementation are part of the same library and thus in sync.

Comment: Besides that, I was never a fan of these `synchronized…` collection wrappers, as real-life operations are almost always compound and require explicit locking anyway. Thus, using an explicit lock in the first place does not give the wrong impression that thread safety was as simple as synchronizing every method. It avoids mistakes like the infamous check-then-act anti-pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real state of the things in OpenJDK/OracleJDK is the following:

- New `spliterator()`, `stream()` and `parallelStream()` methods are not synchronized and must be manually synchronized externally (similarly to `iterator()` or `listIterator()` existed before).
- Other new methods are synchronized including `forEach`, `removeIf`, `replaceAll`, `sort`, `getOrDefault`, `putIfAbsent`, `replace`, `computeIfAbsent`, `computeIfPresent`, `compute`, `merge`.

Such behavior is actually [specified](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedCollection-java.util.Collection-):

> It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned collection when traversing it via `Iterator`, `Spliterator` or `Stream`

So you can expect that any other method except these explicitly mentioned exceptions is synchronized. The subtle problem is that it's specified for `synchronizedCollection` only, but not for other methods and it's not specified explicitly that, for example, `synchronizedList` inherits some behavior from `synchronizedCollection` (though in fact it does).

Note that bulk processing methods like `forEach` or `replaceAll` hold a monitor during the whole iteration, so you finally have a chance to safely iterate/update the whole collection. However you should be aware of possible deadlocks/starvation as collection might be locked for the long time.

Also note that current state introduces the difference between `syncCollection.forEach(...)` and `syncCollection.stream().forEach(...)`: the second call is not synchronized.

**UPDATE**: I [reported](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8141630) to the OpenJDK developers that specification of `synchronizedXXX` methods has to be updated and [submitted a patch](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/dev/jdk/rev/612588a68bd3) which was accepted for JDK-9.

Comment: Yeah, even better, since `Collections.sort` delegates to `List.sort`, applying it to a `synchronizedList`, you gain thread safety *and* potentially high performance execution in the scope of the original list, e.g. when the backing list is an `ArrayList`…